# Multiple Definitions no arquivo moc.o de uma classe

Tags: c++, qt

Estou tendo muitos problemas de multiple definitions no QT. Para classes comuns, e todas as classes da nossa biblioteca, a solução foi colocar o cabeçalho e implementação na mesma .hpp, e dava certo. Para poder usar os slots e signals, eu transformei esta classe, que antes compilava normalmente, em um QObject. Ficando, resumidamente, com este formato:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP
#include "common.hpp"
#include <qtGui>

namespace Bial
{
class Image;

class Myclass : QObject{
    Image *img;
signal:
    void mySignal();
public:
    void f();
}
//Implementação;
#include "Image.hpp"
namespace Bial{
void Myclass::f(){

}

}

#endif //MYCLASS_HPP
```

Porém, ao compilar esse programa recebo muitos erros de multiple definitions (289 no total). Lembrando que MYClass é uma versão resumida da classe PlatefinderController. Os erros se parecem muito com esse abaixo, mas a ssaída do compilador, com os 289 erros pode ser vista em : http://pastebin.com/L9cx7hv9

PlatefinderController.o: In function `Bial::PlatefinderController::NextGroup()':
    /home/lellis/Dropbox/Lellis_Diet/bin/../diet/inc/PlatefinderController.hpp:103: multiple definition of`Bial::PlatefinderController::NextGroup()'
    mainwindow.o:/home/lellis/Dropbox/Lellis_Diet/bin/../diet/inc/PlatefinderController.hpp:103: first defined here

Existe alguma coisa que eu possa fazer pra evitar isso?

Answer (score 2):

Colocar a declaração e definição no cabeçalho não é uma idéia muito boa.

Cada unidade de compilação (ex, .cpp) que incluir esse cabeçalho vai ter uma cópia da definição e por isso você vai ter esses erros de linkedição, a não ser que você force esses métodos a serem inline, mas nem sempre isso é possível.

No caso de classes do Qt isso é menos recomendado ainda pois muita coisa ainda vai ser feita pelo `moc` e novos métodos serão adicionados à sua classe.

Mova a definição de seus métodos para seu próprio arquivo .cpp, se ao fazer isso você está tendo erros de linkedição, melhor buscar entender o motivo disso.